# Retrieve the right clock from the mirror with Java

Tags: java

We're looking at a clock through the mirror and I want to input what we see in the mirror and get the right clock. For example, the input is 3 55 and output (the actual time) is 09:05 with this *conditions 0≤a≤11  0≤b≤59*.

I wrote this code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=scanner.nextInt() , b=scanner.nextInt();
        int h=(6-a)*2+a , m=(30-b)*2+b;
        System.out.printf("%02d:%02d",h,m);
    }
}
```

All inputs are OK except for 0 0. The output is 12:60 which is wrong.

Comment: Interesting... 60 is a "correct" calculation, except that it's outside the range of your acceptable answers (I assume).  Note that for 0 0, humans expect to take the larger value (12) for the hour, but the smaller value (0) for the minutes.  You could add a `% 60` to the end of the calculation for `m` -- `m=((30-b)*2+b)%60`, i suppose.

Comment: @Gus But this will still allow things like `12:59`. I'd also simplify the calculation using some nifty math tricks: `(x-y)*2+y = 2x-2y+y = 2x-y`. Becomes: `h = 12-a` and `m = 60-b`

Comment: I know he's allowed 0 0 as valid input, but I wouldn't assume that 12:59 is invalid; we'd have to get clarification from OP, but that's a time that I see almost daily on my digital clock :)  Good catch on the simplified math.

Comment: oh, I just noticed, 12 isn't valid hour according to his input spec either, so we'd want the `%12` for the hour result too:  `h=(12-a)%12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *java.time*

I would use the standard `java.time` API to avoid too many error-prone complex calculations.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scanner.nextInt(), b = scanner.nextInt();

        if (a >= 0 && a <= 11 && b >= 0 && b <= 59) {
            if (a == 0)
                a = 12;
            if (b == 0)
                b = 60;

            LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(12 - a, 60 - b);
            System.out.println(time);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
3
55
09:05
```

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: How does this fix his issue? Input `0 0` and you'll get an exception. Input `0 1` and you'll get `12:59` which does not fit `0 ≤ hour ≤ 11`

Comment: @BenjaminM - Thanks for pointing it out. I've fixed it now.

Comment: You still have the `hour = 12` issue. You must add `if(a == 0) a = 12`, else you'd be able to input `0 59` and output `12:01`

Comment: @BenjaminM - I also thought about it  but then I realized that the mirror image of 00:00 is actually 12:00.

Comment: But what's the mirror image of `00:01`? Is it `12:59`? That's what your code is doing. I guess that's an implementation detail `:D`